# Kotlin Generate Comment Doc

Tags: javadoc, kotlin

With Java we used to use `/**` before a method and a nice auto-generated doc would just appear. Can't do the same with Kotlin. Is this feature available, turned of by default? How can i turn it on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kotlin documentation tools is called [Dokka](https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka). You can document your code as in java with /**. Take a look to the official docs: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html