# Keyboard shortcut for doc comments in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I want to comment my code like source code comment (JavaDoc).

I have found it before [How to generate javadoc comments in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291785/how-to-generate-javadoc-comments-in-android-studio), but It is for java only, Kotlin is not supported.

That is what I want.
[image]

but I can only do with command + /
[image]

or command + shift + /
[image]

Comment: Use `/** **/` instead of `/* */`

Comment: @Michiel what is the keymap shortcut

Comment: I had a quick look, but I think there is none. It is intended as JavaDoc, so once written, it will always be a comment block. That is probably the reason it can be turned off and on. What you can do: write `/**`and hit enter, it will add a line on every enter.

Comment: @RicardoA. Thanks for suggest.But I have found it before.It is for java only, Kotlin is not support:(

Comment: [Kotlin Generate Comment Doc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38079234/kotlin-generate-comment-doc), [Generating Kotlin method/class comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015307/generating-kotlin-method-class-comments), [Generate KDoc for methods in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574195/generate-kdoc-for-methods-in-android-studio)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54519269/908821 mentioned using a plugin for Kotlin document generation. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10389-kdoc-generator

Comment: Thanks for comment.But it seems that there is no simply shortcut can do what I want just like cmd + /...